# Searching for items in a text file

Tags: python-3.x, io

My text file and my search.py files are in the same folder.

Say there are 10 items ( apple,orange,white,pink,purple,green,sunday,monday,ship,english)
in my text file. I want my code to list all the items that contain the character ('a' in this code below).

It works well for the first character but when I try for the second time for another character it displays nothing.

```
words=open("my_words.txt","r")
count=0
while True:
    a=input("Enter a letter please :")
    print("\n-----------------------")
    for i in words:
        if a in i:
            count+=1
            print(i)
    print("\n-----------------------")

    print("In this list we have", count," items that contain",a)
```

Comment: you could use standard library's `words.count(a)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ur code variable 'words' is a buffer that can be used only once to get file text.

```
I AM ASSUMING THAT THE WORDS IN FILE ARE SEPARATED BY ','.
```

try this:

```
words=open("my_words.txt","r").read().split(',')
count=0
while True:
    a=input("Enter a letter please :")
    print("\n-----------------------")
    for i in words:
        if a in i:
            count+=1
            print(i)
    print("\n-----------------------")

    print("In this list we have", count," items that contain",a)
```

Comment: Thanks, NIKESH SING it works fine on Python Shell...I tested on other python ides and they give error as "text file not found"..Anyway.

Comment: If you don't want the counter to add up, move `count=0` into the while loop.

Comment: Oh, I see. I should have known that. Thanks,daltonfury42